# What file permissions or configurations for CarrierWave in production for Apache2/Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, passenger, carrierwave

I'm running an application using Rails 3.1.3, Ruby 1.9.2, Passenger 3.0.11, Apache2 2.2.14, CarrierWave 0.5.8, and Ubuntu 10.04.

The user of this application is uploading images to the directories "TheApplication/public/uploads/image" and "TheApplication/public/uploads/thumbnail". For this application to upload images properly and securely, what directory/file permissions should I set and what application configurations do I need to set?  Do I need to make any configurations to Passenger or Apache2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's the user of the web server. I expect this to be `"www-data"` on your system.

```
chown -R www-data TheApplication/public/uploads
```

Leave apache and passenger alone.